How can I encode url with OkHttp in kotlin?
I am trying to get historical Bitfinex candle data via public API endpoint provided bt Bitfinex. Trying to use OkHttp in kotlin but continuesly getting empty result. I guess it is encoding problem but could not figure. Url=https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:1h:tBTCUSD/hist?sort=1. If you put the url in browser you get data. But with the below code I get 200 response code but empty response. Please help. Code:
    fun getBitfinexCandleHist():String{

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val url = HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("api.bitfinex.com")
            .addPathSegment("v2")
            .addPathSegment("candles")
            .addPathSegment("trade:1h:tBTCUSD")
            .addPathSegment("hist")
            .addQueryParameter("sort","1")
            .build()
        println(url)
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()
        val call: Call = client.newCall(request)
        val response: Response = call.execute()
        return response.body().toString()
    }



I solved the problem using Unirest code below:

val url = "https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade%3A1m%3AtBTCUSD/hist"
var urlparam = "?sort=+1"
urlparam = "$urlparam&limit=10000"
setDefaultHeaders()
val response: HttpResponse<*> = Unirest.get(url + urlparam)
    .asJson()


I think it is problem of OkHttp. I used Unirest and there was no problem. Code below:
val url = "https://api-b.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade%3A1m%3AtBTCUSD/hist"
var urlparam = "?sort=+1"
urlparam = "$urlparam&limit=10000"
setDefaultHeaders()

val response: HttpResponse<*> = Unirest.get(url + urlparam)
    .asJson()

